# how to force valgrind to show only memory leaks?

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'd like to know how to force Valgrind tool to show only memory leaks!

with `--leak-check=full` or `--leak-check=full` it shows memory leaks (which is good) but also uninitialization problems and/or conditional jump taking problems

thanks!

Comment: Can we ignore the uninitialization problems and/or conditional jump taking problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the uninitialized value reads, including the ones for jumps with `--undef-value-errors=no`. I don't know if you can disable other kinds of errors, such as heap corruption and double free.